# Nonnegative Least Squares Algorithm (NNLS)

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, fitting, linear-algebra

Can anyone optimize the code below which is developed in an old version of Mathematica (2003) both in terms of efficiency and adaption to the latest versions of Mathematica?

**Description of the code:**

Nonnegative least squares (NNLS) is a well-known regression algorithm to fit data as in least-squares, subject to the constraint that all the coefficients are nonnegative. See the full detail at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares).

Upon my earlier [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269686/solution-to-a-linear-equation-with-minimum-rank?noredirect=1#comment672806_269686) and suggestions to use `LeastSquares` and the need for a nonnegative version of it, I found out that Mathematica does not have a built-in command for NNLS.

Luckily, the algorithm due to Lawson and Hanson ["*Solving Least Squares Problems*" (Prentice-Hall, 1974, republished SIAM, 1995)] was implemented by [**Michael Woodhams**](https://www.utas.edu.au/profiles/staff/maths-physics/michael-woodhams) in 2003 and its posted [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2003/Oct/msg00053.html).

For simplicity, I repost Michael's code below. While the code is free to the public, Michael would

> appreciate it if you acknowledge [his] authorship if you use it.

```
(* Coded by Michael Woodhams, from algorithm by Lawson and Hanson, *)
(* "Solving Least Squares Problems", 1974 and 1995. *)
bitsToIndices[v_] := Select[Table[i, {i, Length[v]}], v[[#]] == 1 &];
NNLS[A_, f_] := Module[
      {x, zeroed, w, t, Ap, z, q, \[Alpha], i, zeroedSet, positiveSet,
        toBeZeroed, compressedZ, Q, R},
      (* Use delayed evaluation so that these are recalculated on the
fly as \
needed : *)
      zeroedSet := bitsToIndices[zeroed];
      positiveSet := bitsToIndices[1 - zeroed];
      (* Init x to vector of zeros, same length as a row of A *)
      debug["A=", MatrixForm[A]];
      x = 0 A\[LeftDoubleBracket]1\[RightDoubleBracket];
      debug["x=", x];
      (* Init zeroed to vector of ones,
        same length as x *)
      zeroed = 1 - x;
      debug["zeroed=", zeroed];
      w = Transpose[A].(f - A.x);
      debug["w=", w];
      While[zeroedSet != {} 
          && Max[w\[LeftDoubleBracket]zeroedSet\[RightDoubleBracket]]
> 0,
        debug["Outer loop starts."];
        (* The index t of the largest element of w, *)
        (* subject to the constraint t is zeroed *)
        t = 
          Position[w zeroed, Max[w zeroed], 1, 
                1]\[LeftDoubleBracket]1\[RightDoubleBracket]\
\[LeftDoubleBracket]1\[RightDoubleBracket];
        debug["t=", t];
        zeroed\[LeftDoubleBracket]t\[RightDoubleBracket] = 0;
        debug["zeroed=", zeroed];
        (* Ap = the columns of A indexed by positiveSet *)
        Ap = 
          Transpose[
            Transpose[A]\[LeftDoubleBracket]
              positiveSet\[RightDoubleBracket]];
        debug["Ap=", MatrixForm[Ap]];
        (* Minimize (Ap . compressedZ - f) by QR decomp *)
        {Q, R} = QRDecomposition[Ap];
        compressedZ = Inverse[R].Q.f;
        (* 
          Create vector z with 0 in zeroed indices and compressedZ
entries \
elsewhere *)
        z = 0 x;
        z\[LeftDoubleBracket]positiveSet\[RightDoubleBracket] =
compressedZ;
        debug["z=", z];
        While[Min[z] < 0,
          (* There is a wart here : x can have zeros, 
            giving infinities or indeterminates. They don't matter, 
            
            as we ignore those elements (not in postitiveSet) but it
will \
produce warnings. *)
          debug["Inner loop start"];
          (* 
            find smallest x\[LeftDoubleBracket]
                  q\[RightDoubleBracket]/(x\[LeftDoubleBracket]q\
\[RightDoubleBracket] - z\[LeftDoubleBracket]q\[RightDoubleBracket])
*)
          (* such that : q is not zeroed, 
               z\[LeftDoubleBracket]q\[RightDoubleBracket] < 0 *)
          \[Alpha] = Infinity;
          For[q = 1, q <= Length[x], q++,
            
            If[zeroed\[LeftDoubleBracket]q\[RightDoubleBracket] == 0
&&
                z\[LeftDoubleBracket]q\[RightDoubleBracket] < 0,
              \[Alpha] = 
                Min[\[Alpha], 
                  x\[LeftDoubleBracket]q\[RightDoubleBracket]/(x\
\[LeftDoubleBracket]q\[RightDoubleBracket] - 
                        z\[LeftDoubleBracket]q\[RightDoubleBracket])];
              debug["After trying index q=", q, " \[Alpha]=",
\[Alpha]];
              ]; (* if *)
            ]; (* for *)
          debug["\[Alpha]=", \[Alpha]];
          x = x + \[Alpha](z - x);
          debug["x=", x];
          
          toBeZeroed = 
            Select[positiveSet, 
              Abs[x\[LeftDoubleBracket]#\[RightDoubleBracket]] <
10^-13 &];
          debug["toBeZeroed=", toBeZeroed];
          zeroed\[LeftDoubleBracket]toBeZeroed\[RightDoubleBracket] =
1;
          x\[LeftDoubleBracket]toBeZeroed\[RightDoubleBracket] = 0;
          
          (* Duplicated from above *)
          (* Ap = the columns of A indexed by positiveSet *)
          
          Ap = Transpose[
              Transpose[
                  A]\[LeftDoubleBracket]positiveSet\[RightDoubleBracket]];
          debug["Ap=", MatrixForm[Ap]];
          (* Minimize (Ap . compressedZ - f) by QR decomp *)
          {Q, R} = QRDecomposition[Ap];
          compressedZ = Inverse[R].Q.f;
          (* 
            Create vector z with 0 in zeroed indices and compressedZ
entries \
elsewhere *)
          z = 0 x;
          
          z\[LeftDoubleBracket]positiveSet\[RightDoubleBracket] = 
            compressedZ;
          debug["z=", z];
          ]; (* end inner while loop *)
        x = z;
        debug["x=", x];
        w = Transpose[A].(f - A.x);
        debug["w=", w];
        ]; (* end outer while loop *)
      Return[x];
      ]; (* end module *)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Syed This is more of an informative post rather than a question. Many may be looking for an NNLS algorithm in Mathematica, so they can find it here. It basically provides the best fit to data as in least-squares, subject to the constraint that all the coefficients are nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the effort to share useful code, but StackExchange is a questions/answers site, and does not accept arbitrary discussion. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour I suggest you rewrite this in a Q/A format (self-answered questions are fine) to prevent the thread from getting closed.

Comment: I think that we can test this code and proposed a new one used new functions introduced  in time period 2003-2022.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Absolutely. Michael himself has suggested that his code is not optimal. I guess it can be optimized for the latest versions of Mathematica.

Comment: @FaridShahandeh Could you add code optimization problem to you post?  In turn I have tested Michael's code on matrix $100\times 200$ to compare with modern version `NMinimize`. Timing is 0.03125 and 4.48438 consequently.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I added the question regarding the optimization. I hope contributors improve this.

Comment: Adding a specific example (i.e., data and proposed model rather than just code) to the question should be essential.

Comment: My suggestion to this is that you split off the bits regarding Woodhams's code into an actual answer, and let the question part be dedicated to asking a question. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) as well.

Comment: Note that as an alternative to this method, there is a nice one posted by @CarlWoll [in this prior MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204365/approximate-strictly-positive-solution-to-a-linear-set-of-equations). It uses quadratic programming under the hood.

Comment: Another old-fashioned alternative to guarantee positive coefficients is to transform coefficients in the following manner:  Coefficient `a` is replaced with `Exp[loga]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That's a clever one! Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not actually pose a question.

Answer (score 11):

We can compare 6 algorithms based on `FindMinimum`,`NMinimize`, `ConvexOptimization`, `QuadraticOptimization` with algorithm by Lawson and Hanson implemented by Michael Woodhams. First code (Michael)

```
bitsToIndices[v_] := Select[Table[i, {i, Length[v]}], v[[#]] == 1 &];
NNLS[A_, f_] := 
  Module[{x, zeroed, w, t, Ap, z, q, \[Alpha], i, zeroedSet, 
    positiveSet, toBeZeroed, compressedZ, Q, R}, 
   zeroedSet := bitsToIndices[zeroed];
   positiveSet := bitsToIndices[1 - zeroed];
   x = 0 A[[1]];
   zeroed = 1 - x;
   w = Transpose[A] . (f - A . x);
   While[zeroedSet != {} && Max[w[[zeroedSet]]] > 0, 
    debug["Outer loop starts."];
    t = Position[w zeroed, Max[w zeroed], 1, 1][[1]][[1]];
    zeroed[[t]] = 0;
    Ap = Transpose[Transpose[A][[positiveSet]]];
    {Q, R} = QRDecomposition[Ap];
    compressedZ = Inverse[R] . Q . f;
    z = 0 x;
    z[[positiveSet]] = compressedZ;
    While[Min[z] < 0, debug["Inner loop start"];
     \[Alpha] = Infinity;
     For[q = 1, q <= Length[x], q++, 
      If[zeroed[[q]] == 0 && 
        z[[q]] < 0, \[Alpha] = Min[\[Alpha], x[[q]]/(x[[q]] - z[[q]])];
       ]];
     x = x + \[Alpha] (z - x);
     toBeZeroed = Select[positiveSet, Abs[x[[#]]] < 10^-13 &];
     zeroed[[toBeZeroed]] = 1;
     x[[toBeZeroed]] = 0;
     Ap = Transpose[Transpose[A][[positiveSet]]];
     {Q, R} = QRDecomposition[Ap];
     compressedZ = Inverse[R] . Q . f;
     z = 0 x;
     z[[positiveSet]] = compressedZ;
     ]; x = z;
    w = Transpose[A] . (f - A . x);
    ]; Return[x];];
```

Second code by Jean - Claude Poujade

```
NNLSFindMinimum[A_, f_] := 
  Module[{nbx = Length[First[A]], xi, x, axf, xinit}, 
   xi = Array[x, nbx];
   axf = A . xi^2 - f;
   xinit = PseudoInverse[A] . f;
   If[And @@ (# >= 0 & /@ xinit), xinit, 
    fm = FindMinimum[Evaluate[axf . axf], 
      Evaluate[Sequence @@ Transpose[{xi, xinit}]], 
      MaxIterations -> 1000];
    xi^2 /. fm[[2]]]];
```

Code 3

```
NNLSNMin[A_, f_] := 
  Module[{nbx = Length[First[A]], xi, x, axf}, xi = Array[x, nbx];
   axf = A . xi^2 - f;
   fm = NMinimize[Evaluate[axf . axf], xi];
   xi^2 /. fm[[2]]];
```

Code 4

```
NNLSNMinCon[A_, f_] := 
  Module[{nbx = Length[First[A]], xi, x, axf}, xi = Array[x, nbx];
   axf = A . xi - f;
   fm = NMinimize[{axf . axf, Table[xi[[i]] >= 0, {i, Length[xi]}]}, 
     xi];
   xi /. fm[[2]]];
```

As it well known NNLS problem is equivalent to a quadratic programming problem. With this method we can test

Code 5

```
NNLSN2Min[A_, f_] := 
  Module[{nbx = Length[First[A]], X, x, axf}, X = Array[x, nbx];
   axf = 1/2 X . (Transpose[A] . A) . X - (Transpose[A] . f) . X;
   sol = NMinimize[{axf, Table[X[[i]] >= 0, {i, nbx}]}, X];
   X /. sol[[2]]];
```

Code 6

```
 NNLSNquadratic[A_, f_] := 
  Module[{nbx = Length[First[A]], X, x, axf}, X = Array[x, nbx];
   axf = 1/2 X . (Transpose[A] . A) . X - (Transpose[A] . f) . X;
   sol = ConvexOptimization[axf, Table[X[[i]] >= 0, {i, nbx}], X];
   X /. sol];
```

Code 7

```
NNLSNquadraticOp[A_, f_] := 
  Module[{nbx = Length[First[A]], X, x, axf}, X = Array[x, nbx];
   axf = 1/2 X . (Transpose[A] . A) . X - (Transpose[A] . f) . X;
   res = QuadraticOptimization[axf, Table[X[[i]] >= 0, {i, nbx}], X];
   X /. res];
```

Test

```
SeedRandom[12345];

a = Table[Random[], {i, 100}, {j, 200}];
f = Table[Random[], {i, 100}];

OUT = Array[out, {7}];
```

With these data we test 7 code

```
out[1] = NNLS[a, f] // AbsoluteTiming
out[2] = NNLSFindMinimum[a, f] // AbsoluteTiming;
out[3] = NNLSNMin[a, f] // AbsoluteTiming;
out[4] = NNLSNMinCon[a, f] // AbsoluteTiming;
out[5] = NNLSN2Min[a, f] // AbsoluteTiming;
out[6] = NNLSNquadratic[a, f] // AbsoluteTiming;
out[7] = NNLSNquadraticOp[a, f] // AbsoluteTiming;
```

Compare time and absolute error

```
ListPlot[Table[out[i][[1]]/out[1][[1]], {i, 1, 7}], 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Filling -> Axis]

ListPlot[Table[Abs[out[i][[2]] - out[1][[2]]], {i, 2, 7}], 
 PlotRange -> {10^-13, 10^-7}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
 Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Table[i, {i, 2, 7}], 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image: Figure 1]

As we can see from this picture the fastest code is Code 1 developed by Michael Woodhams in 2003. We can improve  Code 1 by replacing `While` and `For` loop with `Do` loop. But improvement is very small about 10% only and eliminates on a large matrix $10^4\times10^4$. Nevertheless, let consider

Code 8

```
bitsToIndices[v_] := Select[Table[i, {i, Length[v]}], v[[#]] == 1 &];
NNLS1[A_, f_] := 
  Module[{x, zeroed, w, t, Ap, z, q, \[Alpha], i, zeroedSet, 
    positiveSet, toBeZeroed, compressedZ, Q, R}, 
   zeroedSet := bitsToIndices[zeroed];
   positiveSet := bitsToIndices[1 - zeroed];
   x = 0 A[[1]];
   zeroed = 1 - x;
   w = Transpose[A] . (f - A . x);
   Do[If[zeroedSet != {} && Max[w[[zeroedSet]]] > 0,
      t = Position[w zeroed, Max[w zeroed], 1, 1][[1]][[1]];
      zeroed[[t]] = 0;
      Ap = Transpose[Transpose[A][[positiveSet]]];
      {Q, R} = QRDecomposition[Ap];
      compressedZ = Inverse[R] . Q . f;
      z = 0 x;
      z[[positiveSet]] = compressedZ;
      Do[If[Min[z] < 0,
         \[Alpha] = Infinity;
         Do[
          If[zeroed[[q]] == 0 && 
             z[[q]] < 0, \[Alpha] = 
              Min[\[Alpha], x[[q]]/(x[[q]] - z[[q]])];
            ];, {q, 1, Length[x]}];
         x = x + \[Alpha] (z - x);
         toBeZeroed = Select[positiveSet, Abs[x[[#]]] < 10^-13 &];
         zeroed[[toBeZeroed]] = 1;
         x[[toBeZeroed]] = 0;
         Ap = Transpose[Transpose[A][[positiveSet]]];
         {Q, R} = QRDecomposition[Ap];
         compressedZ = Inverse[R] . Q . f;
         z = 0 x;
         z[[positiveSet]] = compressedZ;, Break[]];, {Infinity}
       ]; x = z;
      w = Transpose[A] . (f - A . x);, Break[]];, {Infinity}
    ]; Return[x];];
```

Test 2

```
SeedRandom[1];
a = Table[Random[], {i, 10000}, {j, 12000}];
f = Table[Random[], {i, 10000}];
OUT = Array[out, {10}]; out[2] = NNLS1[a, f] // AbsoluteTiming; 
out[1] = NNLS[a, f] // AbsoluteTiming;

Table[out[i][[1]], {i, 2}]

Out[]= {180.171, 174.289}
```

Comment: Wonderful job Alex, Thanks!

Comment: @FaridShahandeh You are welcome!

Comment: I checked all seven codes against my examples. When $f$ is a matrix, the solutions for each row form a matrix, say $S$. It turns out that only the **second** code returns the $S$ with minimum rank.

Comment: @FaridShahandeh Could you add this test to your post for discussion?