# Can I solve a system for a postive semidefinite variables?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have the following system, where I want to find the solution set consisting of real, nonzero, symmetric positive semidefinite matrices $G$ and $DD$ such that the block matrix $X$ defined below is symmetric and positive semidefinite. I am not sure how to really impose these requirements (for example when I use Solve[] or Reduce[]). Any suggestion?

```
A = {{1/2, 0}, {4/3, 1/2}};
U = {{1, -1/2}, {1, -5/6}};
B = {{19/16, 9/16}, {1/4, 3/4}};
V = {{1, -3/4}, {0, 0}};
DD = {{d11, d12}, {d21, d22}};
G = {{g11, g12}, {g21, g22}};
X11 = DD . A + Transpose[A] . DD - Transpose[B] . G . B;
X12 = DD . U - Transpose[B] . G . V;
X21 = Transpose[U] . DD - Transpose[V] . G . B;
X22 = G - Transpose[V] . G . V;
X = {{X11, X12}, {X21, X22}};
```

**Edit**

I tried the following, but it produced a trivial solution. I understand that it solves the problem but how can I get a nontrivial solution?!

```
A = {{1/2, 0}, {4/3, 1/2}};
U = {{1, -1/2}, {1, -5/6}};
B = {{19/16, 9/16}, {1/4, 3/4}};
V = {{1, -3/4}, {0, 0}};
DD = {{d11, d12}, {d21, d22}};
G = {{g11, g12}, {g21, g22}};
X11 = DD . A + Transpose[A] . DD - Transpose[B] . G . B;
X12 = DD . U - Transpose[B] . G . V;
X21 = Transpose[U] . DD - Transpose[V] . G . B;
X22 = G - Transpose[V] . G . V;
X = {{X11, X12}, {X21, X22}};
Solve[{X == Transpose[X], X >= 0, DD == Transpose[DD], DD >= 0, 
  G == Transpose[G], G >= 0}, {g11, g12, g21, g22, d11, d12, d21, 
  d22}, Reals]
```

> {{g11 -> 0, g12 -> 0, g21 -> 0, g22 -> 0, d11 -> 0, d12 -> 0,    d21
> -> 0, d22 -> 0}}

Comment: Some algorithms for NNLS are  discussed in my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269727/nonnegative-least-squares-algorithm-nnls/269787#269787

Comment: @Manx Are you sure X>=0 impose PSD?

Comment: See Theorem about eigenvalues of PSD matrices. The symmetric matrix A is PSD if and only if the eigenvalues of A are non-negative.

Comment: Maybe I could do that, but I tried what @Manax suggested, and it gave the trivial solution. I have added it to the post.

Comment: A few things: 1) Regarding your block matrix `X = {{X11, X12}, {X21, X22}};` you need to use `X = ArrayFlatten[{{X11, X12}, {X21, X22}}]` to make it a proper matrix. 2) You can make both DD and G symmetric to begin with e.g replace them with `DD = {{d1, d2}, {d2, d3}}` and `G = {{g1, g2}, {g2, g3}}`; 3) If you do this you'll find that `X == Transpose[X]` is automatically true. So it only remains to prove that the eigenvalues of all three matrices are all non-negative.

Comment: @Rudinberry `Solve` has no algorithm to solve optimization problem. Try some of NNLS algorithms linked above.

Comment: It seems as though the maximum of the first eigenvalue of `X` is zero and it always takes negative values. I can't prove this because the eigenvalues take a very complicated `Root` form which will not `Reduce`, but numerically it looks worrying: `evalsX=Eigenvalues[X]; NMaximize[evalsX[[1]], vars]` - and try the various methods . Having also done hours of `FindInstance` too I'm going out on a limb and saying your problem has no solution except the trivial one.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is homogenous so DD = G = 0 is a solution, as you have already noticed. It also seems to be the only solution. Indeed

```
X = ArrayFlatten[{{X11, X12}, {X21, X22}}];
vars = Join[Variables[G], Variables[DD]];
SemidefiniteOptimization[0, 
    VectorGreaterEqual[{X, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}] && 
    VectorGreaterEqual[{G, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}] && 
    VectorGreaterEqual[{DD, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}] && 
    Tr[X] == 1, 
    vars, 
    {"PrimalMinimumValue", "PrimalMinimizer"}
]
```

detects the problem to be infeasible if you ask for the trace of `X` to be different from zero. No luck either if you ask for the trace of `G` or `DD` to be different from zero instead.

For the above to work change

```
DD = {{d11, d12}, {d12, d22}};
G = {{g11, g12}, {g12, g22}};
```

into symmetric matrices.